# How can I check for the data type of a dynamic property upon setting a value to it?

Tags: c#, dynamic

Say I have this class:

```
public class Model {

   public Type DataType { get; set; }
   public dynamic DefaultValue { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to ensure that the data type of DefaultValue matches the assigned type to DataType as soon as a value gets assigned to the property. What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: Why not just use generics for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use Generics for this:

```
public class Model<T> 
{
   public T DefaultValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Correct answer. If variable of type object needs to be type checked. Then make it generic.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the `DefaultValue` to

```
private dynamic _defaultValue;

public dynamic DefaultValue 
{ 
    get => _defaultValue;
    set 
    {
        if (DataType == null) throw new Exception("Set type first");
        if (value.GetType() != DataType) throw new Exception("Wrong type"); 
        _defaultValue = value;      
    }
}
```

Although I imagine this could be better implemented with generics. Also what would happen if `value` is derived from `DataType`?